# Desktop now showing home folders / files. Solutions tried haven't worked

Tags: nautilus, home-directory

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'd just started to get to grips with 20.04 when my desktop suddenly started showing the home directory contents.

I've found a couple of possible solutions, but they haven't worked.

`~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` is showing `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"`

I used

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

and edited the line to

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

It appears to save, but it's gone on a restart and the folders and files are still there. If I use `sudo gedit`, I receive `dconf-Warning "dbus-launch"` errors.

I also tried the Dconf Editor to go into the Nautilus preferences looking for `desktop_is_home_dir` but that line is not there.

Has anybody got any ideas, and be aware I am new to linux/Ubuntu?

If I enter

```
ls -l $HOME/Desktop
```

I get

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 colin colin 19 Feb  7 16:03 /home/colin/Desktop -> /home/colin/Desktop
```

Comment: Does `$HOME/Desktop` actually exist? what are its permission modes (`ls -l $HOME/Desktop`)?

Comment: It shows the following

rwxrwxrwx 1 /home/colin/Desktop -> /home/colin/Desktop

Comment: Please [edit] the `ls -l` output into your question so the formating doesn't go astray - it looks like you have somehow ended up with a recursive symbolic link?

Comment: Done. I'll have to read up on what a recursive symbolic link is.

Comment: If this link is what's causing the problem then I'm not sure how to remove it (I don't know how it occurred in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely what's happening is that `xdg-user-dirs-update` (which is run when you start a new desktop session) is noticing that `$HOME/Desktop` is not a directory, and is resetting the value of `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` to your home directory instead, undoing your changes to the user-dirs.dirs file. From the man page:

> If an old configuration exists it is updated with any new default
> directories. Additionally, any configured directories that point to
> non-existing locations are reset by pointing then to the users home
> directory. This typically happens when the users removed the
> directory,    so they likely don't want to use it anymore.

Since `/home/colin/Desktop` is a link to itself, you can just remove it and recreate it as a regular directory:

```
rm "$HOME/Desktop" && mkdir "$HOME/Desktop"
```

**then** make your changes to user-dirs.dirs. After that, they should be applied next time you log in.

Comment: That worked. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @punking happy to help

Comment: My Desktop is turning into a symbolic link on restart.